# AddClass e RemoveClass não executam conforme esperado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo um select que ao ser alterado para determinado valor deve remover a classe 
`col-md-9` e adicionar a classe `col-md-4` para encaixar um novo campo na tela.
Ele deve ficar como o exemplo.

[image: Como deve ficar]

Porém quando altero para o select desejado ele não surte nenhum efeito.

O estranho é que faço o mesmo com outro campo (quando coloca em outro valor do select) e o mesmo funciona normalmente (sendo feitos da mesma forma, alterando o nome dos campos óbvio).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#input-produto').change(function () {
         matricula_produto();
     });


    function matricula_produto() {
        let val = $('#inputs_socios option:selected').attr('pcasal');
        if (val == 1) {
           $('.input-produto').addClass('col-md-4').removeClass('col-md-12');
           $('.input-vinculo').insertAfter($('.input-produto')).show();
        } else {
        $('.input-produto').addClass('col-md-12').removeClass('col-md-4');
        $('.input-vinculo').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group input-produto col-md-12">
   <label for="inputs_socios">Produto*</label>
   <select name="inputs_socios" id="inputs_socios" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Escolha</option>
      <option pcasal="0">SÓCIO 1</option>
      <option pcasal="1">MUDAR</option>
      <option pcasal="0">SÓCIO 3</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6 input-vinculo" style="display:none">
   <label for="seq_vinculo">Vinculado</label>
   <select name="seq_vinculo" id="seq_vinculo" class="form-control">
      <option pcasal="0">TESTE</option>
      <option pcasal="1">TESTE2</option>
      <option pcasal="0">TESTE3</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Se eu rodar o comando `$('.input-produto').addClass('col-md-4').removeClass('col-md-9');` no console ele funciona, mas não esta rodando na hora que precisa. Porém o outro valor esta. E ele esta entrando no `if` pois o campo esta aparecendo, só não esta adicionando e removendo a classe.

Comment: Consegue elaborar um [mcve] demonstrando o problema? O Snippet do site tem a opção de adicionar o jQuery.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Adicionei o snippet.

Comment: Guilherme, esse código jQuery não deveria estar dentro de um evento, tipo `change`, do `<select>`? Da forma que ele está será executado quando a página carregar, não quando o valor for alterado.

Comment: No código ele esta dentro de uma função que verifica toda vez que ele é alterado. Tanto que como mencionei no post um outro campo que é praticamente um Ctrl+c Ctrl+v tem o comportamento esperado com esse código.

Comment: E se eu copiar o código e colar no console ele funciona como deveria.

Comment: Então adicione esse trecho também ao exemplo, senão ele não reproduzirá fielmente seu problema.

Comment: Não é possível adicionar isso pois a função é muito grande, e chama outras funções que acaba ficando confuso para adicionar somente essa parte.

Comment: Guilherme, mas é exatamente para isso que serve o MCVE. Ao fazer um exemplo que reproduza o erro, você garante que o erro está no código que nos apresentou. Dizer que não é possível reproduzir porque há muito código que não está na pergunta abre uma margem imensa para que o erro esteja justamente na parte que omitiu. Se o exemplo mínimo (como apresentado na resposta) funciona, então com certeza o erro está em alguma outra parte do código, o que torna sua pergunta insuficientemente clara e impossível de responder.

Comment: O código em si referente a isso é só um change.

Comment: Então adicione a parte que trata o evento `change` na pergunta para elaborar o [mcve] necessário.

Comment: Adicionei agora .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, adcione

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

para esperar o código ter sido renderizado para executar o html.

e adicione o evento

```
 $('#inputs_socios').on("change", function(){
```

para que quando toda vez que o select for alterado executar a ação que deseja, conforme exemplo abaixo :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#inputs_socios').on("change", function(){
          let val = $('#inputs_socios option:selected').attr('pcasal');
        if (val == 1) {
            $('.input-produto').addClass('col-md-4').removeClass('col-md-12');
            $('.input-vinculo').insertAfter($('.input-produto')).show();
        } else {
            $('.input-produto').addClass('col-md-12').removeClass('col-md-4');
            $('.input-vinculo').hide();
        }
      });

   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group input-produto col-md-12">
   <label for="inputs_socios">Produto*</label>
   <select name="inputs_socios" id="inputs_socios" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Escolha</option>
      <option pcasal="0">SÓCIO 1</option>
      <option pcasal="1">MUDAR</option>
      <option pcasal="0">SÓCIO 3</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6 input-vinculo" style="display:none">
   <label for="seq_vinculo">Vinculado</label>
   <select name="seq_vinculo" id="seq_vinculo" class="form-control">
      <option pcasal="0">TESTE</option>
      <option pcasal="1">TESTE2</option>
      <option pcasal="0">TESTE3</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Sem sucesso. já havia feito algo parecido.

Comment: O que me intriga é que se eu colar o código no console funciona.

Comment: funciona, por que no momento que você executou o código  a página já tinha sido carregada totalmente, no entanto, na aplicação ele é executado de imediato.

Comment: Como solucionar isso.

Comment: Aplicando o $(document).ready(function(){ como disse e fiz na resposta

Comment: Se você executar o código do snippet você irá ver que funciona, se no seu caso não está funcionando, é por que existem códigos que não estão em sua pergunta, por favor complemente a pergunta com o código restante.

Comment: Já está assim @MarcianoMachado

Comment: Mas no snippet não funciona, ele esta apenas rodando o show e não o `addClass()` e o `removeClass()`

Comment: O nome do id do seu select está errado em um lugar você está utilizando #inputs_socios e outro #input-produto

Comment: Opa, dei uma debugada aqui e já achei o problema, é na logica mesmo. O que acontece é que ele esta executando os addClass e Remove, porém depois ele acaba caindo em um else la embaixo que verifica outras coisas e removendo isso. Com o debbuger achei o problema. Muito obrigado por dispor do seu tempo para tentar me ajudar.